# clone(java.io.Serializable & T) in SerializationUtills cannot be applied to (T)

Tags: java

I'm trying to generify a clone method but I'm getting this error:

```
clone(java.io.Serializable & T) in SerializationUtills cannot be applied to (T)
```

The method is the following:

```
public <T> T clone(T t) {
    T t1;
    synchronized (t) {
        t1 = SerializationUtils.clone(t);
    }
    return t1;
}
```

How can I solve the error?

Comment: Hows your clone method defined in SerializationUtils? and what's the actual error?

Comment: @almasshaikh SerializationUtils is a class of org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils
The error comes when I try to clone t: clone(java.io.Serializable & T) in SerializationUtills cannot be applied to (T)

Answer (score 2):

Because `.clone` wants it's argument to be serializable, you have to guarantee that is the case.

```
public <T extends Serializable> T clone(T t)
```

Should fix the error you are getting ... And then you will get another :) Something like "Cannot convert Serializable to T". There isn't much that you can do about that other than a cast:

```
t1 = (T) SerializationUtils.clone(t);
```